# INSERT Trigger not firing an update?

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers

Ok so i have a fairly basic trigger :

In words, After Insert, Get IP information and update the Inserted row with the new data

```
CREATE TRIGGER [BasicData.IPInfo.Gather]
ON [BasicData]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @City VARCHAR(1000),
        @Country VARCHAR(1000),
        @IP VARCHAR(1000),
        @ROWID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

    SELECT @IP=[IP],@ROWID=[ID] FROM [inserted]

    SELECT @Country = [Country], @City= [City]
    FROM [IPInfo] WHERE [IP] = @IP

    IF (@City IS NOT NULL) AND (@Country IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN -- Never seems to fire
            UPDATE [BasicData]
            SET [IPCountry]=@Country,[IPCity]=@City
            WHERE [ID] = @ROWID
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN -- Fired correctly
            INSERT INTO [IPInfo.Missing] VALUES (@IP)
        END
END
```

Now the problem is, It adds the missing IP information correctly (Only when missing), however, it does not seem to ever update the table when it does, What am i missing?

Ive tweaked it in every possible way i could think of... (My trigger knowledge is rather bad)

Comment: I want it to fire when the data is inserted, once it is inserted, it should immediately update it, no update trigger is required for this AFAIK

Comment: what other triggers if any do you have on that table. if you replace your update statement with a insert into a dummy table, does that work? Try out a few different way to see what's up

Comment: No other triggers, and on a dummy table it works like a charm

Comment: Weird. This shouldn't make a difference, but can you change your update to - update basicdata set country=b.country,city=b.city from basicdata a , ipinfo b where a.id=(select id from inserted) and a.ip=b.ip

Comment: Any table/user permissions that could be blocking this trigger? You said dummy table works like a charm. Does you account have any permission restrictions?

Comment: Could you provide a simple but comprehensive enough setup in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to demonstrate both the situation when the trigger should insert into `[IPInfo.Missing]` and the one when it should update `BasicData`? I realise that you've already confirmed that the trigger seems to work fine when the UPDATE statement is replaced with an INSERT into a dummy table. Yet, for us to be able to spot the problem and help you out of it, it *may* be helpful if we had an opportunity to work with the schema as close to yours as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

1. INSERTED can contain many rows. Your trigger allows for only one.
2. The trigger is AFTER INSERT, and I guess this might exclude UPDATEs. Try `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE`
3. Your IF statement isn't checking for an UPDATE - what if the column is UPDATED to NULL? it won't catch it even though it was an update. What if something inserted NON NULL data? it will think it was an UPDATE.

As far as I know the only way to identify an UPDATE is to join  `INSERTED` and `DELETED on the PK. If there is a match, it's been updated.

Perhaps you could rewrite it like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [BasicData.IPInfo.Gather]
ON [BasicData]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

-- Save UPDATES to BasicData
UPDATE [BasicData]
SET [IPCountry]=I.Country,[IPCity]=I.City
FROM [BasicData] UT
INNER JOIN
[inserted] I
ON I.ID = UT.ID
INNER JOIN
Deleted D
ON D.ID = I.ID
INNER JOIN
[IPInfo] IP
ON I.ID = IP.ID

-- Save inserts to Missing
INSERT INTO [IPInfo.Missing] (IP)
SELECT IP FROM
INSERTED I
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DELETED D WHERE D.ID = I.ID)

END
```

Comment: 1) This table only ever gets one row inserted at once. 
2) I have tried after insert, no luck. 
3) The specific column does not allow nulls

Comment: 1) I suggest that is not very defensive programming 2) Do you mean to say you tried AFTER UPDATE? I tested and only putting AFTER INSERT doesn't pick up updates, whereas AFTER INSERT, UPDATE does.